# How to read properties file in java, which has value in key-value pair

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

if properties file contains below type values how to read it directly into map

```
user={'name':'test','age':'23','place':'london'}.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can read to value as a JSON and use Gson to convert it to Java Objects

Comment: What map format you want? Key is `user` and value is `{'name':'test','age':'23','place':'london'}`?

Comment: the value should be in map format. I trying to read like this @Value("${user}")

Answer (score 8):

You can inject values into a Map from the properties file using the `@Value` annotation like this.

```
@Value("#{${user}}")  
private Map<String, String> user;
```

Entry in your application.properties must be:

```
user = {"name":"test","age":"23","place":"London"}
```

Comment: I have tried this but I am getting error Unexpected token. Expected 'rcurly(})' but was 'colon(:)'

Comment: Sure. Can you share the complete stack trace. Also the applications.properties file

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userInterceptor' while setting constructor argument;

Comment: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userInterceptor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.hp.cis.common.interceptor.UserInterceptor.user; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 19): Unexpected token.

Comment: Expected 'rcurly(})' but was 'colon(:)'

Comment: will it work only any specific version of spring. I am using spring 3.xx

Answer (score 2):

**test.properties file**

```
name=test
age=23
place=london
```

**code**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadPropertiesFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("test.properties");
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fileInput);
            fileInput.close();

            Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
            while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
                String value = properties.getProperty(key);
                System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope, this would help.. :)

Comment: Before doing this.. please convert your object file into the 'key'='value' format.

Comment: The question is explicitely for a properties entry in jSON.

Comment: I guess he can do, this thing :) (the conversion) as I already mentioned. @jokster

Answer (score 1):

This will read a property file and put it in `Properties` object.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesConfig {

    private Properties prop;

    private PropertiesConfig() {
        super();

        init();
    }

    private static class PropertiesInstance {
        private static PropertiesConfig instance = null;

        public static PropertiesConfig getInstance() {
            if (null == instance) {
                instance = new PropertiesConfig();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public static PropertiesConfig getInstance() {
        return PropertiesInstance.getInstance();
    }

    private void init() {

        prop = new Properties();
        try (InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample_config.properties")) {

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return prop.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

Now you can use any library to convert a value to Map as your value looks like a JSON.

Code example to achieve this through Jackson:

```
public static Map < String, Object > covertFromJsonToMap(String json) throws JsonTransformException {
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference < HashMap < String, Object >> () {});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error " + json, e);
        throw new JsonTransformException("Error in json parse", e);
    }
}
```

So something like this will do:

```
covertFromJsonToMap(PropertiesConfig.getInstance().get("user"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a JSON representation of your map as a value. Once you read the value as a String in Java you can use Gson to convert it to map

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = <YOUR_STRING>
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map = (Map<String,Object>) gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
```